# Outer scope variable not registered in contained functions

Tags: python, java

I was coding this code snippet provided as a leetcode solution in Python but found that my variable `flag` isn't available.

```
public class Solution {
    boolean flag = false;
    
    public boolean checkInclusion(String s1, String s2) {
        permute(s1, s2, 0);
        return flag;
    }
    
    public String swap(String s, int i0, int i1) {
        if (i0 == i1)
            return s;
        String s1 = s.substring(0, i0);
        String s2 = s.substring(i0 + 1, i1);
        String s3 = s.substring(i1 + 1);
        return s1 + s.charAt(i1) + s2 + s.charAt(i0) + s3;
    }
    
    void permute(String s1, String s2, int l) {
        if (l == s1.length()) {
            if (s2.indexOf(s1) >= 0)
                flag = true;
        } else {
            for (int i = l; i < s1.length(); i++) {
                s1 = swap(s1, l, i);
                permute(s1, s2, l + 1);
                s1 = swap(s1, l, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I rewrote it in Python together with the checks. What I did was move the helper functions to be part of the `checkInclusion` function so that the helper functions can run within the context of, for lack of a better word, "main" function. What I noticed is that my assertions fail. In trying to debug, I tried to print out the `flag` variable but nothing was printed out.

```
from typing import List
class Solution:
    def checkInclusion(self, s1: str, s2: str) -> bool:
        def swap(string: str, left: int, right: int) -> str:
            stringList = list(string)
            stringList[left], stringList[right] = stringList[right], stringList[left]
            return "".join(stringList)

        def permute(string:str, left: int, right: int, permutations: List[int]) -> List[int]:
            """left and right are indices for the string"""
            if left == right:
                permutations.append(string)
                return permutations
            else:
                for i in range(left, right+1):
                    swapped = swap(string, left, i)
                    permute(swapped, left+1, right, permutations)

                return permutations

        permutations = permute(s1, 0, len(s1)-1, [])
        # print("permutations =", permutations)
        for permutation in permutations:
            if permutation in s2:
                return True

        return False

# brute force - NOT creating a list of the permutations
# n = len(s1)
# m = len(s2)
# Time : O(n! + nm) - creating the permutations and nm for 
#       comparing the s1 in s2. Depends on relative size of s1 and s2
#       to determine what dominates
# Space: O(n!) - n! for the list of permutations, O(n x n) for the 
#        recursion tree depth and length of the string but n! dominates
#        for large n.
from typing import List
class Solution:   
    def checkInclusion(self, s1: str, s2: str) -> bool:
        flag = False
        def swap(string: str, left: int, right: int) -> str:
            stringList = list(string)
            stringList[left], stringList[right] = stringList[right], stringList[left]
            return "".join(stringList)

        def permute(s1: str, s2: str, pos: int) -> None:
            print("flag in permute =", flag)
            if pos == len(s1):
                print("flag in if statement", flag)
                if s2.find(s1) > -1:
                    flag = True
            else:
                for i in range(1, len(s1)):
                    s1 = swap(s1, pos, i)
                    permute(s1, s2, pos+1)
                    s1 = swap(s1, pos, i)

        permute(s1, s2, 0)
        return flag

sol = Solution()
s1 = "x"
s2 = "ab"
assert sol.checkInclusion(s1, s2) == True

s1 = "a"
s2 = "ab"
print(sol.checkInclusion(s1, s2))
assert sol.checkInclusion(s1, s2) == True

s1 = "ab"
s2 = "eidbaooo"
assert sol.checkInclusion(s1, s2) == True

s1 = "ab"
s2 = "eidboaoo"
assert sol.checkInclusion(s1, s2) == False
```

The error I got doesn't print out `flag`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "567. Permutation in String.py", line 75, in <module>
    assert sol.checkInclusion(s1, s2) == True
  File "567. Permutation in String.py", line 68, in checkInclusion
    permute(s1, s2, 0)
  File "567. Permutation in String.py", line 57, in permute
    print("flag in permute =", flag)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'flag' referenced before assignment
```

Although I would like to know how to make a better conversion into Python, I feel I am missing a crucial bit of information on why `flag` appears to be assigned before it is referenced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError trying to use a variable (supposed to be global) that is (re)assigned (even after first use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-trying-to-use-a-variable-supposed-to-be-global-that-is-rea)

Comment: Unless you are trying to design a submission for leetcode.com or similar, you don't need the `Solution` class at all in Python. Python, unlike Java, has modules that allow top-level functions and variables, rather than the rigid one-class-per-file restriction that Java imposes.

Comment: I would also like it to work for leetcode too. I agree that I don't need the `Solution` class but it is part of learning Python to know how to do it when constrained with it.